Are the junior officer quarters in Lower Decks literally in a hallway?
This question makes the assertion

"Lower Deckers" in Star Trek: Lower Decks literally sleep in the walls
of the corridors

but I've always figured that the "corridors" shown outside the bunks of Boimler (et al) are walkways inside a larger internal bunkroom, not the corridors in general use in the ship. Is there any canonical evidence whether I'm correct or mistaken.

Senior officers and others are seen walking past the end of the corridor. That doesn't make much sense if it is internal to a bunkroom.

Nope. These are hallways.

Boimler: So, yeah, we kind of sleep in a hallway. It's a little disappointing, but eventually, when you rank up, you get your own room.
LD: Second Contact


This is pretty analogous to how sailors sleep in submarines, they usually are arranged two- or three-high in hallways like this, and are frequently crammed between functional parts of the ships, so they are essentially general-use hallways, like this. Boimler is lucky they aren't hot-bunking.

@Plutor - If you've got time to worry about sex, you've got too much time on your hands. It sounds like someone needs to be assigned some extra duties, like cleaning carbon off the carbon filters.

@Velorum: they probably just bake it into their buffer time.

@Valorum: I may be missing something here, but FYI, "hot-bunking" doesn't have to do with sex.
